# Seeking 1945 New Jersey Death Record

Tags: death-records, vital-records, 1940s, new-jersey

I am looking for the complete death record of John Kalashi (+ Oct 1945) who passed away in Atlantic City NJ.

According to Reclaim The Records, [some years of the index are missing](https://www.reclaimtherecords.org/records-request/21/), including 1930-1948.

Is there a way to access this record?

Known facts :

- He lived in Philadelphia in 1917 [WWI draft].
- He lived in Atlantic City in 1930 and 1940 [census].
- He lived in Atlantic City in 1942 [WWII draft].
- He died and is buried outside Atlantic City in 1945.
- His SS# is 138 03 0735

Comment: It is easier for people to find information on the site if we have one question per question.  I have edited out the part of your question about seeking his naturalization record since it is a different type of record, entirely unrelated to death records.  Please post that as a separate question so you can retain authorship of the question. You can link back to this question to refer to his timeline.

Comment: I have updated my answer because I think I may have figured out what the NJ Department of Health means about the date ranges available for their records. If you do order the death record from them and find out what the real answer is, please let me know so I can update the answer. I do have research interests in NJ but I haven't ordered certificates from them.

Comment: I sure will. In case I contact them -very likely- I'll post the update here.

Comment: And please do post the naturalization question as a new question. I would love to take a crack at it!

Comment: Done. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not ordered certificates from New Jersey yet and have written this answer based on what I could find online. Please direct questions about the current availability of certificates to either the NJ Department of Health or the NJ State Archives (as appropriate).

According to the FamilySearch Research Wiki Article, [New Jersey Vital Records](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/New_Jersey_Vital_Records), historical copies of birth and death records are at the New Jersey State Archvies, and modern ones are held by the Bureau of Vital Statistics. The article refers the reader to the website of The New Jersey Department of Health and Senior Services. Their page on ordering [genealogical records](https://www.state.nj.us/health/vital/order-vital/genealogical-records/) is not exactly clear on which records might be restricted due to privacy laws. It says:

> ```
>  Genealogical Records (family history research) are:
>
>  Birth, death and marriage records for people who are deceased    
>
>  AND where 
>
>  the birth occurred more than 80 years ago until 1921 
>  the marriage occurred more than 50 years ago until 1931 
>  the death occurred more than 40 years ago until 1931 
>
>  Your request cannot be processed as a genealogical request if 
>  the person named on the record is still living or the event 
>  was more recent than listed above.
> ```

The dates in the statements about what birth, marriage, and death records are available may be a combination of two different things.  I suspect the wording "until 1921" for births and "until 1931" for marriages and deaths refers to a rolling window for transferring the records to the New Jersey State Archives, and the "more than 80 years ago, more than 50 years ago, and more than 40 years ago" wording refers to privacy rules which cover when records may be released to the public.

Note that the FamilySearch Wiki article says you can order records up to the current day. This may be referring to the orders by close family members.  Read the page at the New Jersey Department of Health carefully and ask them to clarify if needed.

The FamilySearch Wiki article says "Be sure to request the "long form." If the exact date is unknown, there is an additional fee for each year searched."  You already have the month and day (presumably from the Social Security Death index), but you might be able to get the exact date by doing research in local newspapers, or from cemetery records (since you know his burial location). Once you have the exact date, contact the State of New Jersey and ask them to clarify if death records from 1945 can be ordered.

Proof of relationship is not required for informational copies. The page on ordering genealogical records has advice on what information is required and which is optional. Providing his Social Security Number will help them ID the person you want so you won't get a certificate that belongs to someone else with the same name.