# Naturalization Record

Tags: united-states, naturalization

This is a follow-up to a [Seeking 1945 New Jersey Death Record](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18616).

I am looking for the naturalization record of *Jani Keleshi* (birth name).

He was born in Berat, Albania during the 1890s; at that time it was part of the Ottoman Empire.

Here is what I have so far (chronologically):

1910 Arrival ???

1917 U.S., World War I Draft Registration Cards
Name:   *John Keleshi*
Marital Status: Single
Birth Date: *25 Dec 1890*
Birth Place:    Albania
Residence Place:    Philadelphia, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, USA

1930 United States Federal Census
Name:   *John Kalashi*
Birth Year: abt 1894
Age in 1930:    36
Birthplace: Albania
Marital Status: Single
Home in 1930:   Atlantic City, Atlantic, New Jersey, USA
Immigration Year:   *1910*
Naturalization: **First Papers (Pa)**

1940 United States Federal Census
Name:   *John Kalaski*
Age:    48
Birthplace: Albania
Marital Status: Single
Home in 1940:   Atlantic City, Atlantic, New Jersey
Residence in 1935:  Atlantic City
Citizenship:    **Naturalized**

1942 U.S., World War II Draft Registration Cards
Name:   *John Ilia Kalashi*
Gender: Male
Birth Date: *27 Dec 1891*
Birth Place:    Berat, Albania
Residence Place:    Atl, New Jersey, USA

1945 Tombstone
Name:   *John Kalashi*
Birth Date: 7 Jan 1891
Death Date: 15 Oct 1945
Cemetery:   Atlantic City Cemetery
Burial or Cremation Place:  Pleasantville, Atlantic County, New Jersey

1945 U.S., Social Security Applications and Claims Index
Name:   *John Kalashi*
Birth Date: *25 Dec 1896*
Birth Place:    Albania
Death Date: 15 Oct 1945
Claim Date: 16 Oct 1945
SSN:    **138 03 0735**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FamilySearch has some collections for Atlantic County, New Jersey, that may be useful:

- [Declarations of intention, 1883-1925](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/154755)
- [Naturalization records, 1837-1929](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/320337)

In the Declarations of intention 1883-1925 vol 1, A-Z there is a record for "Kaleski, Jani also as John Kaleski": https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-89Q4-775Z?i=75&cc=2057433&cat=154755

[image: Kaleski declaration index]

| Name | Address | Date of filing | Declaration number | Volume number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kaleski, Jani also as John Kaleski | 229 N. South Carolina Ave. Atlantic City NJ | Dec. 10-1923 | 3545 | Volume 10 |

Then, in the Declarations of intention 1923-1924 vol 10, no 3301-3600, record 3545 shows "Jani Kaleski, known as John Kaleski", age 31, occupation cook. His birth place appears to be [Berat, Albania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berat) and his birth date 25 December 1892.

https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-89Q4-L7BT?i=161&wc=M73T-1ZS%3A351145601%2C351283301&cc=2057433

[image: Kaleski declaration]

The naturalization index shows John Kalashi or Kalaski, living on the same street as in the John Kalashi in the 1940 census, was naturalized on Nov. 26, 1940. FamilySearch does not appear to have the full naturalization records for 1940, just the index.

https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-99Q4-VYY8?i=33&cc=2057433&personaUrl=%2Fark%3A%2F61903%2F1%3A1%3A6CBG-WT32

[image: Kaleski naturalization index]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you read his month of arrival? I am guessing April, but I am not certain.

Comment: I think it is April. That is an old-fashioned cursive p, also seen in "Naples" after "I emigrated to the United States of America from ___."